# Jest test using react-test-renderer is inserting undefined attribute value into the DOM

Tags: jestjs, react-test-renderer

I briefly tried to find this in the react-test-renderer source code, but wasn't able to locate it.

Recall that in React, component element attributes whose values are `undefined` are not rendered in the DOM.  I.e., given `bat = undefined` and `<Foo bar={bat} />`, the `bar` attribute will not appear in the generated HTML.

I'm assuming it's expected behavior, but I'm confused why, when an optional component attribute appears in the JSON tree in a Jest snapshot - unless the snapshot is simply confirming that the property is unspecified (`ws-automation-id` is an optional component property that does not have a `defaultProps` entry defined):

```
exports[`the <TextButton/> component should use the specified class names 1`] = `
<button
  className="gc-icon test-class1 test-class2"
  onClick={[Function]}
  ws-automation-id={undefined}
>
  Button Text
</button>
`;
```

Given

```
test('should use the specified class names', () => {
  const tree = create(<TextButton buttonText="Button Text" onClick={null} classNames={['test-class1', 'test-class2']} />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I neglected to post the version being used at the time of the original post.  This issue has been fixed, however, it's unclear as to the exact version.

Answer (score 0):

this is expected.

> Essentially, this package makes it easy to grab a snapshot of the platform view hierarchy (similar to a DOM tree) rendered by a React DOM or React Native component without using a browser -- [React Test Renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html)

It's not exactly the DOM tree you'd see from a browser inspect, rather a javascript object representing something similar.